# Downloading files in Custom NSIS Page

Tags: nsis

I want to create an installer that downloads a file without freezing the UI using the inetc plugin. My question is that possible **without** using the ExecDos::Exec with the /ASYNC flag and then ExecDos::Wait.

In addition , i do not want installation page in my installer. 
Here is my code:

```
!macro DOWNLOAD_PAGE
    Function myTimer
        ${If} $0 == "OK"
            ${NSD_KillTimer} myTimer
            SendMessage $hPBar ${PBM_SETRANGE32} 0 100
            SendMessage $hPBar ${PBM_SETPOS} 100 0
            Return
        ${EndIf}

        SendMessage $hPBar ${PBM_SETRANGE32} 0 100
        SendMessage $hPBar ${PBM_SETPOS} 50 0

    FunctionEnd

    function Page1
        nsDialogs::Create 1018
        Pop $Dialog

        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 50% "Starting download..."
        Pop $hInfo

        ${NSD_CreateProgressBar} 0 55% 100% 10u ""
        Pop $hPBar

        ${NSD_CreateTimer} myTimer 1000
        inetc::get /silent "$URL\skype.exe" "$EXEDIR\skype.exe" /end
        Pop $0
        nsDialogs::Show
    functionEnd 

    function Page2
    functionEnd 
    Page Custom Page1 Page2
!macroend

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Docs\Modern UI\License.txt"

  !insertmacro DOWNLOAD_PAGE
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

Or the only option i have is using the ExecDos::Exec with the /ASYNC flag?
Perhaps, a solution it is to create another nsis installer that does the download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing a long operation between `nsDialogs::Create` and `nsDialogs::Show` will hang the UI.

The easy solution is to download in a `Section` because those are executed in a different thread. You are supposed to perform most of your tasks in a `Section`.

If you insist on downloading something on a custom page then you can use the [InetBgDL plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/InetBgDL_plug-in):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Custom Page1
Var hInfo

Function Page1
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 50% "Starting download..."
Pop $hInfo

InitPluginsDir
INetBgDl::Get "https://example.com/file.exe" "$PluginsDir\file.exe" /end

${NSD_CreateTimer} myTimer 1000
nsDialogs::Show
${NSD_KillTimer} myTimer
FunctionEnd

Function myTimer
InetBgDL::GetStats
${NSD_SetText} $hInfo "Status=$0$\nCompleted files=$1$\nDownloaded $3 of $4 bytes"
${If} $0 = 0 ; HTTP status code or 0 if completed without errors
    ${NSD_KillTimer} myTimer
    MessageBox mb_ok Done
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me.